# The multi-part identifier " " could not be bound

Tags: sql

I get an error:

> The multi-part identifier "archivebook.idarchivestorage" could not be bound.

```
    SELECT barcode
         , name
         , code
         , yearfrom
         , yearto
         , archivenumber
         , c.line
         , c.regal
         , c.shelf 
      FROM archivebook AS A  
INNER JOIN archiveclassifications AS B  
           ON A.idclassification = B.id 
           AND dateofstatus <= '2019/09/26' 
           AND dateofstatus >= '2019/09/24' 
INNER JOIN administration.dbo.ArchiveStorage C 
           ON archivebook.idarchivestorage = C.id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have assigned aliases to the table names.  *Use them*:

```
select ?.barcode, ?.name, ?.code, ?.yearfrom, ?.yearto, ?.archivenumber,
       ars.line, ars.regal, ars.shelf
from archivebook ab join
     archiveclassifications ac
     on ab.idclassification = ac.id and
        ?.dateofstatus <= '2019-09-26' and
        ?.dateofstatus >= '2019-09-24' inner join 
        administration.dbo.ArchiveStorage ars
        on ab.idarchivestorage = ars.id;
```

The `?` is for the appropriate table alias.  You should qualify *all* columns references, especially when a query refers to more than one table.  This is a good habit to get into, so it is even more important if you are learning SQL.

Note that I changed the aliases so they are appropriate abbreviations for the table names.  This makes it much easier to read and maintain the query.